# Calculate PDF of difference of Max and Min for Gaussian random variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

Although this should be a standard question I didn't find it in SE, and it was a nice exercise in Mathematica.

Let $x$ and $y$ be two independent Gaussian random variables with distribution $N(0,1)$.

Let $t = \max(x,y) - \min(x,y)$.

1. Calculate the PDF of $t$
2. Discuss the 1st and 2nd moments
3. Generalize to $n>2$